# Manwhua where weak mc becomes strong and summons the demon king of another universe

Tags: story-identification, manga

From what I recall, the mc is very weak but kind hearted and he tries to save a little girl chased by assassins, she gives him a ring and he held into it. He doesn't know his father but will later be trained by him. After a few years he is taken to a place to get a familiar, he ends up with a snake who's the demon king of its universe. There are multiple classes in this manwhua and the mc wants to become a protector knight, I think, like his father.